# UWP DataContext datatype changed due to async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, windows-10

I have a XAML page like this

```
<Page
x:Class="MyPrj.View.PageA"
....
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
     <Grid Background="{ThemeResource TOPApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <UserControlB x:Name="UserControl_B" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In the OnNavigatedTo of PageA, I call an async method

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ModelA a = await GetObject(id);
        UserControlB_ViewModel viewModel = new UserControlB_ViewModel();
        viewModel.X= a.X
        viewModel.Y= a.Y;           
        UserControlB.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

Then in the UserControl_Loaded of UserControl_B, I get the context as below

```
  private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControlB_ViewModel viewModel = (UserControlB_ViewModel)this.DataContext;
        ...
    }
```

And GetObject function

```
 private async Task<ModelA> GetObject(string id)
    {
        ModelA a = null;
        var endpoint = new Uri(Constants.GetObjectById);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var content = new StringContent(LoginPage.CurrUser.Token);
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(content, Constants.WebserviceLink.Token);
        content = new StringContent(id);
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(content, "id");

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, multipartFormDataContent);

        var contents = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(contents);
        switch (ret.RetCode)
        {
            case Code.InvalidToken:
                CommonHelper.MessegeDialog(Constants.ErrorMessage.InvalidToken);
                break;
            case Code.Exception:
                CommonHelper.MessegeDialog(Constants.ErrorMessage.LoadDataFail);
                break;
            case Code.Success:
                a =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelA>(ret.DataObject.ToString());
                break;
        }

        return a;
    }
```

The issue is that, after run through the `var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(server, multipartFormDataContent);` line inside GetObject(), the UserControl_Loaded function of UserControlB will be invoked and exception thrown at `UserControlB_ViewModel viewModel = (UserControlB_ViewModel)this.DataContext;`, indicating that this.DataContext is actually of PageC_ViewModel

If I didn't call the async function inside OnNavigatedTo of PageA, the casting of data context inside UserLoad_Control of UserControlB would work well. Any idea why does this go wrong?

Comment: I think it would be useful to ses implementation of  `GetObject(id)`.

Comment: It calls a web service and cast the result to object @stt106

Comment: I see that right after the await function call, UserControl_Loaded will be invoked. Codes underneath await call will not be invoked

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean when you call `await GetObject(id)` , the implementation of `GetObject(id)` triggers the `UserControl_Loaded` event and its event handler throws a casting exception hence you said the code after `await GetObject(id)` is not invoked? And if you simply do `GetObject(id)` (without await), the code works fine?

Comment: There's another async function invoked inside GetObject(). After that one is invoked, UserControl_Loaded will be triggered and the exception was thrown. I've updated the code for GetObject() and give more explanation

Comment: I guess the next obvious question is to figure out why `await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, multipartFormDataContent);` would trigger the event `UserControl_Loaded` being fired.

Comment: Yes that's it. Do you have any idea ?